# Another way to say [X]

Tags: creative-writing

I was composing an answer to one of these questions (that we get all the time), and when I tried to submit it, I found that the question had been placed on hold. Rather than discard the answer that I had spent some time composing, I thought that I would re-post the question in a more general form.

Here is the original question:

> My character loses an argument, and gives up. The line is "Willa backed down reluctantly." I'm trying to avoid the adverb 'reluctantly', but I can't think of anything.

This is really a creative writing question, not English Language & Usage, and belongs on another site. However, a canonical answer may serve as a useful duplicate, and allow us to provide some sort of assistance, rather than send people away with fleas in their ears.

Comment: This question probably belongs on *meta*, but I posted it here to get some notice. Feel free to move it.

Comment: How about "Willa backed down"?

Comment: I agree about eliminating unnecessary adverbs and adjectives, and that is sometimes my answer, too.

Comment: By the way I don't think there is a SE site for what the user was asking.  Writers.SE doesn't allow that sort of question either.

Answer (score 2):

**Show, don't tell:**

> Don't tell me the moon is shining; show me the glint of light on broken glass. -- Anton Checkov

Instead of sitting here, racking my brain, trying to think of some obscure word that will meet your needs, let me ask you two questions: Why are you trying to write pedestrian prose? Instead, why don't you study successful authors, and learn how they handle "Show, don't tell."?

I opened my copy of Hilary Mantel's *Wolf Hall* at a random page (p.188) and this is what I found:

> Gregory looks at him, wary, puzzled. His glance flinches; his hand pulls away. 'The dogs will kill it,' he says.

This is written in the present tense, which will have to be fixed, but the framework will serve us well. In the context, Gregory is being offered a kitten as a pet. All we have to do is change a few words:

> Willa looks at him, wary, puzzled. Her glance flinches; her hand pulls away. 'All right,' she says.

As it stands, this is direct plagiarism, so you will need to change the actions to describe your character's exact feelings, and you may also need to change the tense (Mantel likes to write in the present tense.) However, we have managed to show the character's feelings without having to think of some obscure adverb, and we haven't had to mention *backing down* at all.

Warning: If you are writing for a class exercise, be sure to acknowledge your source (Mantel, in this case). Your teacher will recognise the technique, and may even recognise the author, if you use the present tense.

[Wikipedia: Show, don't tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell)

Hilary Mantel, *Wolf Hall*, Fourth Estate, 2010